# Dict comprehension taking much longer than expected

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm profiling my simulation code, and I noticed a dict comprehension was taking quite a while.

The dict comprehension looks like this:

```
return {
  n : self.method(d) for n, d in zip(ns, ds)
}
```

The `self.method` took about 40% of the call, but this is expected because this method is expensive (it queries a database), and the other 60% appears to be from the overhead of the dict comprehension call according to `cProfile`.

Is there a faster way to write the above?

I was expecting dict comprehension to take a negligible amount of time.

Comment: What is the size of your dict?

Comment: What are the types of `n` and the return value of `self.method`?

Comment: @9769953 the number of keys should be around ~50. return value of `self.method` is a dict of dicts. the outer dict is probably around ~5000 keys and the inner dict is 2 keys mapping to floating point values

Comment: @9769953 i'm actually not sure if the return value of `self.method` is counted as part of the 40% or the 60% in cProfile. if it's part of the 60%, then I think that makes more sense

Comment: " dict of dicts. the outer dict is probably around ~5000 keys": I think that that might be your problem. The resulting dict grows rapidly, and Python needs to reallocate new memory quite often; possibly also shuffling the old data to its new memory. If you can find a way to preallocate the memory beforehand, that will be faster.

Comment: A use case to optimise a dict of a dict with 5000 keys (and then an inner dict), suggests it might be better to use a different data type altogether. Consider using NumPy (recarrays or perhaps just ordinary arrays) or Pandas. With Pandas, multi-index might be useful with your nested dict: the multi-index would consists of the several layers of keys. You can then calculate the size beforehand, and allocate the necessary memory in one go, after which you start assigning values into the array or dataframe/series. Altogether, that will faster than what you're currently doing.

Comment: Please read the `Help others reproduce the problem` section af [ask], specifically the [mre] suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a faster way to write the above?

Possibly, but finicky, and perhaps just not really worth it.

The underlying problem is likely:

> dict of dicts. the outer dict is probably around ~5000 keys

The resulting (comprehension) dict grows rapidly, and every so often, Python needs to allocate new memory (depending also on the size of the 5000 values); possibly also shuffling the old data to its new memory location. If you can find a way to preallocate the memory beforehand, that will be faster. But I've no idea how to do that, and that's not really the intention when using Python (memory allocation should be invisible to a user/programmer).

The case to optimise a dict of a dict with 5000 keys (and then an inner dict), suggests it might be better to use a different data type altogether. Consider using NumPy (recarrays or perhaps just ordinary arrays) or Pandas. With Pandas, multi-index might be useful with your nested dict: the multi-index would consists of the several (3, afaict) layers of keys. You can then calculate the overall size beforehand, and allocate the necessary memory in one go, after which you start assigning values into the array or dataframe/series. Altogether, that will faster than what you're currently doing.

Comment: Let me describe the use case of the return value. The outer dict has some integer ID for the key (the integer keys are usually O(10^6), e.g., 1000000, though I don't think this matters), and downstream, we need want to be able to quickly the value (the inner dict of size 2) the dict for a given ID. I've actually never heard of rearrays, but I know I can do this with pandas, we won't be able to get as fast access as with a dict, though perhaps the lack of reallocation at the cost of slower access results in a faster overall simulation.

Comment: @u2j4 "we won't be able to get as fast access as with a dict": I would think a Pandas Series is comparable a Python dict with regard to access speed. Best way to find out is to try it, but there are a few more factors at play. For example, 1/ are all the ~50 dicts with ~5000 items the same length? 2/ what is the inner dict? Does each inner dict have the same two keys? Are the two values the same type? Because the answers to that might lead to an actual optimization (or not); just trying out a single replacement might not show a speed-up, while a further rehash of the code might.

Comment: 1) I need to check on this, but I think so (each of the 50 dicts has the same number of keys -- they might also be the same keys, I'll have to confirm)

2) yes, the inner dict have the same 2 keys. the key is a string and the value is a floating point value.

Comment: To point 2: it seems that could be replaced by a 2-element list, and you use indices 0 and 1 instead of the 2 keys. If the keys of the large dict are all the same, you could even think of using a two-dimensional 5000 by 2 (or a 2 by 5000, depending on the access pattern; order matters!) NumPy array. It may take some effort to replace the keys with indices, but once coded right, I think you can get an enormous speed up. In the end, you might end up with a 50 by 5000 by 2 three-dimensional array. Harder to think about accessing an element (no dict keys!), but much, much faster to operate on.

Comment: Just coming back to this now. I changed the outer dict to a numpy array length 50 array. Each element of the numpy array is a dict of dicts. The outer dict is not guaranteed to have the same keys or the same number of keys as I previous stated, unfortunately, but it's usually between 5k-6k. Are you suggesting to use an array for this dict of 5k-6k or a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the amount of Python code by building the dictionary using built-in functions:

```
return dict(zip(ns,map(self.method,ds)))
```

I don't think this  will make a big difference though.